# Move product tags to WooCommerce product description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, product

I need to move product tags to bottom of WooCommerce product description.

I am using *"[Add custom content to WooCommerce product description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577599/add-custom-content-to-woocommerce-product-description/45579735#45579735)"* answer code that really works and I get text "This is the last line in the description" below product description...

Now I would like to add the product meta information (the product SKU and the tags), but I don't catch how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

I am using a Storefront child theme…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product meta data is displayed with the template `single-product/meta.php`, So you just need to call it using the dedicated function `wc_get_template()`.

Now as this is used in a filter hook where the display is returned using a variable, you need to enable PHP buffering…

That is the final code:

```
// remove the product meta data
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );

add_filter( 'the_content', 'woocommerce_product_description_and_meta' );
function woocommerce_product_description_and_meta( $content ) {

    // Only for single product pages (woocommerce)
    if ( is_product() ) {
        global $post, $product;

        ob_start(); // Start buffering

        // The product meta information
        wc_get_template( 'single-product/meta.php' );

        // Inserting the product meta information display at the end
        $content .= ob_get_clean(); // append the buffered display
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

It be done in a different way: [Move product meta to the description tab in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57790167/move-product-meta-to-the-description-tab-in-woocommerce/57791923#57791923)

Comment: It works. I rejoice as a child. Half a day killed on this. And I don’t even understand how you did it. Or rather not, you did it in a completely different way than I could have imagined. Thank you!