# Move only product tags from WooCommerce single product metatags to product description

Tags: php, woocommerce, tags, metadata, product

I am using [Move product tags to WooCommerce product description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57828563/move-product-tags-to-woocommerce-product-description/57829036#57829036) answer code, but it moves the whole section, with everything I have there: sku, categories. I want to move only the tags part to another area.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Please stop picking up existing code to add it in your question, just if it was from you and without providing the credits and the original link. I kindly remember you, that we expect you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to remove the tags by editing the template: `/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php`. You will need to remove the entire row:

```
<?php echo wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', count( $product->get_tag_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' ); ?>
```

See [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) to learn how.

At this point you will have successfully removed the tags from the `meta.php` template. Now you will need to add them where you want them. Using your function, you can get it like this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'woocommerce_product_description_and_meta' );
function woocommerce_product_description_and_meta( $content ) {
   // Only for single product pages (woocommerce)
   if ( is_product() ) {
      global $product;
      $tags = wc_get_product_tag_list( $product->get_id(), ', ', '<span class="tagged_as">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', count( $product->get_tag_ids() ), 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</span>' );
      $content .= $tags;
   }
   return $content;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer.
It seems to be part of woocommerce. At the next update it can appear back or deleting it to create issues (not being a mega expert).
Is there a better option, with the total addition of a snippet?

Comment: And yes, the add code works perfectly.

Comment: Check out the link in my answer. To prevent future updates from overwriting customizations to template files you will need to create a child theme, in your case the modified `meta.php` file will be added in: `themes/child-theme/woocommerce/single-product/meta.php`.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I will try this option.
Of course.

Comment: I'll be back. I think I found a simpler option for me:
div.product_meta .tagged_as  {
display: none !important;
}
I used this css and then the code above to get where I want